# JS google maps (Добавление информера к маркеру)

Tags: google-maps-api, java, javascript

Нашел js который позволяет добавлять маркеры (иконки) на гугл мапс при нажатии на которого выскакивает информер с описанием. Только вот одна беда. В этом демо примере работает так только одна иконка а в java я дуб дерево. Не подскажете как и остальные маркеры сделать активными? что бы выскакивал информер при нажатии как и на первой.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize() {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0442, 9.9116);
                var settings = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
                var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Hogenhaug</h1>'+
                    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                    '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>';
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
                });

                var companyImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://plc.com.ua/images/maps/logo.png',
                    new google.maps.Size(100,50),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    new google.maps.Point(50,50)
                );

                var companyShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://plc.com.ua/images/maps/logo_shadow.png',
                    new google.maps.Size(130,50),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    new google.maps.Point(65, 50));

                var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0442, 9.9116);

                var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: companyPos,
                    map: map,
                    icon: companyImage,
                    shadow: companyShadow,
                    title:"Hogenhaug",
                    zIndex: 3});

                var trainImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://plc.com.ua/images/maps/train.png',
                    new google.maps.Size(50,50),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    new google.maps.Point(50,50)
                );

                var trainShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://plc.com.ua/images/maps/train_shadow.png',
                    new google.maps.Size(70,50),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    new google.maps.Point(60, 50)
                );

                var trainPos = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0429, 9.9173);

                var trainMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: trainPos,
                    map: map,
                    icon: trainImage,
                    shadow: trainShadow,
                    title:"Train Station",
                    zIndex: 2
                });

                var parkingImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://plc.com.ua/images/maps/parking.png',
                    new google.maps.Size(50,50),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    new google.maps.Point(50,50)
                );

                var parkingShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://plc.com.ua/images/maps/parking_shadow.png',
                    new google.maps.Size(70,50),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    new google.maps.Point(60, 50)
                );

                var parkingPos = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0437, 9.9147);

                var parkingMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: parkingPos,
                    map: map,
                    icon: parkingImage,
                    shadow: parkingShadow,
                    title:"Parking Lot",
                    zIndex: 1
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(companyMarker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map,companyMarker);
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:300px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном примере присутствует обработчик для клика по маркеру "companyMarker", согласно которому открывается информация из contentString. Для того чтобы выскакивал информер для другой иконки, например, parkingMarker необходимо добавить в код:

```
var contentString2 = '<div id="content">'+
                '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Bla bla bal</h1>'+ '</div>';
var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString2
            });
google.maps.event.addListener(parkingMarker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow2.open(map,parkingMarker);
});
```

Данный код лучше использовать только для понимания процесса создания инфоблоков.

Comment: ура)))))) спасибо!!!